# ajax downloading file with struts2

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, struts2

I am using `js` to download file from a server with struts2. Everything works fine except that sometimes generating of the file could take few seconds and I would like to show a loader `gif` from the moment generation starts til the moment that browser shows window for downloading generated file.

For now in my `js` i have:

```
    var url = "myAction.action?param1=" + param1;
    window.location.href = url;
```

This will just call my action that will generate the file that will be downloaded and then browser will show its default download window.

Is there a way to do the same with ajax, so I can know when request started and when response from the browser to the user arrived?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/execute-and-wait-interceptor.html

Comment: the thing is that while waiting for the generation to be finished, some html elements of my application needs to have a specific class. For example one div needs to have a class "loading". I dont see how can I accomplish that with execute and wait interceptor and result "wait" in struts.xml.